# Linux unattached chroot or directory?

Tags: linux, unix, root, chroot

Would it be possible to chroot or otherwise create an unlinked(in the main root file system) directory? From what I understand, the kernel automatically deletes any file/folder that has no link in the file system, but is there a way to have a second root?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, and quite possibly you already have several of those. Remember that you can have several independent filesystems mounted at various places – and every single one of these has its own "root".

For example, if a separate "data" partition is mounted at `/mnt/data`, then that directory is in fact a filesystem root, with no `..` that would point above it. (The same applies also to internal filesystems such as /sys or /dev.)

On Linux, the VFS layer – "virtual filesystem" – makes this work. It allows root 1 to be accessible at `/` and root 2 at `/mnt/data`, and it creates the illusion of `/mnt/data/..` linking to `/mnt`.

---

(Again on Linux, the VFS has a few other interesting features usually used for `/`. For example, when the kernel starts, `/` is attached to an empty "tmpfs" filesystem, where the initramfs is unpacked. Eventually, the main root filesystem is mounted somewhere at `/new_root` or such, and *moved to `/`* using either the special `pivot_root` or the more general `mount --move`. Plus, of course, you've already mentioned `chroot`.

In other words, the VFS root directory is not necessarily born such.

It is possible to have several VFS roots at once – not only by chroot, but also using mount namespaces, where different processes can see different VFS mounts entirely; this is used by 'containers' such as Docker.)

---

However, it is not true that the filesystem root has no links. It only has no links from *above*, but it can easily have links from *below* – in regular subdirectories (such as /bin) the `..` *is* a real link, so `/` would have links from `/bin/..`, `/etc/..`, and so on.

(Interestingly, this is why you can rename read-only directories but not move them elsewhere, because the latter would require writing to the directory to update its `..` link.)